# ZookKeeper Recipes Dependencies

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am new to zookeeper and trying to use some of the zookeeper recipes that are implemented here: https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/tree/trunk/src/recipes. so that i  dont have to build them myself.

Seems like they are not distributed as part of the zookeeper libraries in maven central etc. What is the convention in the zookeeper community? Should i just pull the source and build them myself? Or am i missing something and they are readily available to consume from a central repo.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question, but...

Perhaps you'd find Curator (https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki) useful?  We sure have so far.  It has many of the base ZooKeeper recipes implemented and is bundled as separate maven dependencies.